# Map/Iterating through List of Python Object

Tags: python, dictionary, python-itertools, functools

Is there a way to iterate and call a function on a list of user-defined Python objects with multiple attributes? Let's suppose it's called Entry, with attribute name, and age.

Such that I can say something to the effect of

```
def func(name, age):
    //do something

def start(list_of_entries)
    map(func, list_of_entries.name(), list_of_entries.age()) 
    //but obviously the .name and .age of the object, not the iterable
    //these are the only two attributes of the class
```

Was thinking about using functools.partial() but not sure if that is even valid in this case.

Comment: Is there a reason accessing `name` and `age` in `func` is not sufficient?

Comment: why wouldn't you just pass each entry in list_of_entries into func() and then just access name/age via the object you've passed in?

Comment: to calculate: "list_of_entries.name()" you could use map!

Comment: For an evil direct answer: `map(lambda e: func(**e.__dict__), list_of_entries)`. (PS: please don't do this, it's terrible and will break on any object with `__slots__`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suppose you could use a lambda function:

```
>>> def start(list_of_entries):
...     map((lambda x:func(x.name,x.age)), list_of_entries)
```

But why not just use a loop?:

```
>>> def start(list_of_entries):
...     for x in list_of_entries: func(x.name, x.age)
```

or if you need the results of func:

```
>>> def start(list_of_entries):
...     return [func(x.name, x.age) for x in list_of_entries]
```

Comment: But that last one would pass callables in to the function, where I would assume the OP wants values.

Comment: I was assuming that ".name" and ".age" were properties; if they're callables, then yes you should call them (in all three examples).    In the OP's example, he's calling ".name()" on a list, which doesn't make much sense, so I took it as pseudocode.

Comment: +1 on "using a loop". Using `map` or a comprehension when you're discarding the value feels wrong. (Also, doesn't Python 3.x make `map`, `filter` et al. return iterators instead of evaluating immediately?)

Answer (score 0):

You could use operator.attrgetter() that allows to specify several attributes but explicit list comprehension is better:

```
results = [f(e.name, e.age) for e in entries]
```

Comment: just make it parens and you get a generator too -- which is nice if want to lazily evaluate your list as you need items.

Answer (score 0):

If name and age are the only two attribs you can use vars. Otherwise, add **kwargs to your func and ignore the rest.

```
def func(name, age, **kwargs):
    //do something with name and age


def start(list_of_entry):
    map(lambda e: func(**vars(e)), list_of_entry)
```